# "template" keyword not needed? [gcc/clang/Comeau bug?]

Tags: c++, templates, g++

Here is the test code

```
template <class T> void f()
{
  T t;
  t.f<T>(0); //compiles even without the "template" keyword, what am I missing?
}

class abc
{
  public:
  template <typename T>
  void f (int){}
};

int main()
{
  f<abc>();
}
```

I am using g++ 4.4.6. Thanks

P.S: I have edited my question considerably. Please don't mind.

**EDIT**  : I asked this question to EDG people and this is what Mike Herrick had to say

> We do diagnose this as an error in --strict mode as well as any mode that enables dependent name lookup (e.g., --dep_name, --parse_templates).  Dependent name lookup is disabled in GNU emulation modes, so we don't emit this error in that case.
>
> Dependent name processing requires that nonclass prototype instantiations
>   be enabled (see below).  As with nonclass prototype instantiations, enabling
>   dependent name lookup is likely to cause compilation errors when compiling
>   code that was not written with the feature in mind.
>
> The dependent name lookup rules require that nondependent names be
>   looked up at the point of use in the template definition, and that
>   overload resolution be performed on nondependent calls at that point.
>   For dependent calls, the set of names considered is the set visible
>   at the point of use in the template definition plus any names made
>   visible by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation.
>   Note that built-in types have no associated namespaces, so calls
>   with only built-in types can only resolve to names visible in the
>   template definition.  Furthermore, names from dependent base classes
>   are not visible to unqualified lookups.

The following illustrates some of the most common code problems encountered
when using dependent name lookup:

```
template <class T> struct B {
    void f();
  };

template <class T> struct A : public B<T> {
    X x;  // error: X not visible yet (formerly an error in strict mode)
    void g() {
      f();        // error: B<T>::f not visible
      this->f();  // must be written this way
      h(1);  // error: h(int) not visible using argument-dependent lookup
    }
  };
struct X {};
void h(int);
A<int> ai;
```

Comment: If you rename the member `f` so it doesn't share the name of the global `f`, this won't compile on GCC without specifying `template`. I don't know why that makes a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `template` keyword *is* required both because `t` is a dependent name and because `f<T>` is a dependent member function template specialization.  The relevant specification is scattered throughout clause 14, but starts at §14.2/4 (in both C++03 and C++11).

The problem is due to incorrect name lookup:  gcc is finding the namespace-scope function template `f` at the point of declaration, then at the point of instantiation resolves `f` to the member function template of `abc`.

If you rename either the namespace-scope function template or the member function template, you will get the correct behavior from the compiler.

This is a longstanding gcc bug:

> [Code with missing "template" keyword wrongly accepted](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11814)
>
> [Weird clash with same names in different scopes](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10200)

See also the many duplicate bugs resolved against both of those.  I don't see a Clang bug open for this.

Name lookup from within a function template was underspecified in C++03; there were many defects reported on the subject and the specification  has undergone major changes in C++11 to clarify details and corner cases and to fix subtle problems.

Comment: Even Comeau doesn't give any error. I believe it is the most standard conforming compiler that we have today.

Comment: Ok I am going to report this bug to EDG.:-)

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong, but I think this is a bug in GCC. Consider the following case:

```
template <class T> bool f() {T t = {2}; return t.f < 4;}

struct abc { int f; };

int main() { f<abc>(); }
```

I would expect that to compile just fine, but GCC (and Clang) assume that `t.f` names a template function, and expect a closing `>`. The relevant part of the standard is `§14.2/4`.

That said, I am a bit hesitant to claim that a bug like this could exist in both Clang and GCC without some more evidence. I will get back after some more standard diving.

Comment: Hmmm, I would be interested in the real answer to this question. The behaviour of all the compilers that I have tried is contrary to my understanding of the standard, so I might be able to learn a lot.

Comment: If I rename the member `f` so it doesn't share the name of the template function, this compiles successfully on GCC. See also my comment to the question.